# SQL Case / if value from other CASE is empty

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have a SQL query where is have for a name a german and a english translation available. Based on the user settings and the existing data for translation i want to define the SQL query output. In my example the CASE for choosing the language based on the user setting is working but the second CASE function is not working because it does not know the definition from the first CASE function.

I am working on XAMPP v3.2.4 / Server-Version: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Here is my try:

```html
SELECT questionaire.quest_name_de, questionaire.quest_name_en,

# CASE 1: check what language settings the user haves selected
CASE :language WHEN 'de' THEN questionaire.quest_name_de ELSE questionaire.quest_name_en END AS quest_name_translation,

# CASE 2: if the output is empty take german translation which is never empty
CASE quest_name_translation WHEN '' THEN questionaire.quest_name_de ELSE quest_name_translation END AS quest_name_final
 
FROM questionaire
```

My desired output is as following:

The user language settings is englisch so the first CASE function in my query will select 'questionaire.quest_name_en'. As next the second CASE function will check if the data for 'quest_name_translation' is not empty. If its empty then choose 'questionaire.quest_name_de'.
My problem is that the second CASE does not know 'quest_name_translation' from the first CASE. is this method not possible?

Comment: let me suggest you to remove PHP code from the question, it will make your question much clearer. Instead, better add the database server name and version

Comment: Sorry but which PHP code do you see? I have just added a SQL query and my question i directly about this CASE function in the SQL query. Why the database name is relevant and which version number do you want to know? Really not sure what you want from me. I am sorry but do you mixed up here some questions?

Comment: `$statement = $pdo->prepare` is PHP for instance. The SQL starts with `SELECT`. SQL dialects differ, and what works in one DBMS may not work in another. So, tag your SQL requests always with the DBMS you are using. And ideally you tell us the version, too, because that also may make a difference.

Comment: I hope it is now as you expected^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` to combine conditions. Only if English is requested and English is available will you show the English text, otherwise German:

```
SELECT
  questionaire.quest_name_de,
  questionaire.quest_name_en,
  CASE WHEN :language = 'en' AND quest_name_en <> '' AND quest_name_en IS NOT NULL
    THEN quest_name_en
    ELSE quest_name_de
  END AS quest_name_final
FROM questionaire;
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` would be simpler.

Comment: @thorsten Kettner, thank you for this perfect working solution!

Comment: Do i need "AND quest_name_en IS NOT NULL" as well if the table row is defined as text and not as as INT? I  guess you have added this to avoid "0" as result, right?

Comment: If the column is defined as NOT NULL, then NULL is not possible, but otherwise the text can be empty in two ways: either as NULL or as the empty string ''. But you are still right, `quest_name_en <> ''` already excludes NULLs, too. So, no, `quest_name_en IS NOT NULL` is not necessary.

Comment: @wildplasser: I doubt that. What would that `COALESCE` expression look like that elegantly checks the requested language and considers both null and the empty string?